# Run on my webpage another .html page on small screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created on my website an empty webpage, I name it NewGame.

I have an .html name itm.html and I want to make it run in small  300x300 screen on my page NewGame.html. As long as I didn't find anything how can I do that.

I have searched in here or google or I was trying to do with href but that will redirect me to another page and I don't want that to happen.

Is it possible to run itm.html inside another .html in small screen area, like a youtube small video?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Using Iframe can be a solution https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

Comment: What you're looking for is called *embedding*. Checkout the [`<iframe>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) element which does just that.

Comment: iFrame or ajax the page into a DIV if from the same origin

Comment: thanks guys I appreciated

Comment: the `iframe` is not indexed by search engines. Why not use the `load()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you should use an iframe.

`<iframe src="/itm.html" width="300" height="300"></iframe>`

Put that in NewGame.html. Since both HTML files are on the same domain, it will create a "window" into the other webpage.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to read up on the venerable `iframe` element:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

A quick example:

```css
iframe.myCoolIframe {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<iframe class="myCoolIframe" src="https://example.com/itm.html"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the embed tag in html and style it to the size you want.

```
<embed src="https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_embed.asp" width="300" height="200">
```